# How do I create a function in Java, that can be called with many types?

Tags: java, function, class

what I mean is something like this:

```
function f(int a) {

}
function f(double a) {

}
function f(string a) {

}
```

I want to make a function that can be called with the same name (`f`) and the same variable's names (`a`), but not the same types (`int`, `double` etc.)

THANKS!

Comment: That is what you called Overloading a Method.

Comment: You don't declare functions in Java with a keyword `function`. If that was intended as the return type, the type name should follow the Java naming conventions. Functions, called "methods" in Java, must be members of a type, which you don't show. Other than that, you can do what you want by doing what you did, declaring versions of the function that operate on different types.

Comment: Variable names in a function declaration are placeholders, used internally by the function but imposing no naming requirements on its clients.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for generics:

**instance method:**

```
public <T> void f(T a) { // T can be any type
    System.out.println(a); // test to see  `a` is printed
   // Do something..
}
```

**class method:**

```
public static <T> void f(T a) { // T can be any type
    System.out.println(a); // test to see  `a` is printed
    // Do something..
}
```

Assuming this is inside your `main` method, you can call the class method like so:

**Example 1:**

```
int number = 10;
f(number);
```

**Example 2:**

```
String str = "hello world";
f(str);
```

**Example 3:**

```
char myChar = 'H';
f(myChar);
```

**Example 4:**

```
double floatNumber = 10.00;
f(floatNumber);
```

and any other type.

Further reading of [Generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm).

[Java Documentation of Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: They might be looking for generics. Or they might be looking for overloads. Or they might be looking for function references. Or they might be looking for lambdas, which would involve generics but for Interfaces already in the Java API.

Comment: @LewBloch I certainly agree with you but I couldn't possibly suggest him all the possible ideas. This answer just seems to be the thing I thought of when the question was asked. Nevertheless thanks.

Comment: @LewBloch Also, if you've any suggestions to make the answer better feel free to edit it and i'll accept if I see fit.

Comment: I think just putting the ideas in a comment and allowing the OP to search about them and return with specific questions is optimal here, plus some of this is covered in other answers.

Comment: @LewBloch I see :).

Answer (score 3):

Java classes can have methods of the same name, but different parameter types, just like you're asking for.

```
public class Foo {

    public void f(int a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void f(double a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void f(String a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.f(9.0);
        f.f(3);
        f.f("Hello world!");
    }

}
```